# Axios Typescript, fetching from openweathermap api causes bad request or ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, axios, openweathermap

Im having issues connecting to openweathermaps API in my express app,

```js
app.get("/", cors(), async (req, res) => { 
    const lat: number = + req.query.lat;
    const lon: number = + req.query.lon;
    if (lat && lon) {
        const entry = cach.filter(e => e.lat === lat && e.lon === lon);
        if (entry.some(e => (Date.now() - e.last_updated < 36000000))) {
            res.json(entry[0]);
        } else { // no entry found
            res.json(await getWeather(lat, lon));
        }

    }
    res.send("no location specified")
});
app.listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log(`App is listening on port ${PORT}`); //5000 by default
});
```

to fetch the data im using axios:

```js
async function getWeather(lat: number, lon: number) {
    try {
    const res = await axios({
        url:`http:api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid=${process.env.WAPI}`,
        method:"GET"
    });
    const data = res.data;
    ...
    catch (error){
        console.log(error)
    }
```

but the response i get is:

> App is listening on port 5000
> at Wed Dec 09 2020 15:22:21 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time): http://localhost:5000/?lat=65.58415&lon=22.15465: GET request

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
> >at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1133:16)

```json
 {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 80,
  config: {
    url: 'http:api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=65.58415&lon=22.15465&appid=--apiket--',
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.21.0'
    },
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    data: undefined
  },
  request: <ref *1> Writable {
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: false,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: false,
      ended: false,
      finished: false,
      destroyed: false,
      decodeStrings: true,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: true,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: null,
      buffered: [],
      bufferedIndex: 0,
      allBuffers: true,
      allNoop: true,
      pendingcb: 0,
      constructed: true,
      prefinished: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: true,
      autoDestroy: true,
      errored: null,
      closed: false,
      closeEmitted: false,
      [Symbol(kOnFinished)]: []
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      response: [Function: handleResponse],
      error: [Function: handleRequestError]
    },
    _eventsCount: 2,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _options: {
      maxRedirects: 21,
      maxBodyLength: 10485760,
      protocol: 'http:',
      path: 'api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=65.58415&lon=22.15465&appid=--apikey--',
      method: 'GET',
      headers: [Object],
      agent: undefined,
      agents: [Object],
      auth: undefined,
      hostname: null,
      port: null,
      nativeProtocols: [Object],
      pathname: 'api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather',
      search: '?lat=65.58415&lon=22.15465&appid=--apikey--'
    },
    _ended: true,
    _ending: true,
    _redirectCount: 0,
    _redirects: [],
    _requestBodyLength: 0,
    _requestBodyBuffers: [],
    _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
    _currentRequest: ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: 0,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      _closed: false,
      socket: [Socket],
      _header: 'GET api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=65.58415&lon=22.15465&appid=--apikey-- HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/0.21.0\r\n' +
        'Host: localhost\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: 'api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=65.58415&lon=22.15465&appid=--apikey--',
      _ended: false,
      res: null,
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'localhost',
      protocol: 'http:',
      _redirectable: [Circular *1],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    _currentUrl: 'http:api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=65.58415&lon=22.15465&appid=--apikey--',
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  response: undefined,
  isAxiosError: true,
  toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
}
node:internal/process/promises:225
          triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
          ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:278:15)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:563:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/home/johanrh/Documents/Git/M7011E_AJ/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/home/johanrh/Documents/Git/M7011E_AJ/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
    at /home/johanrh/Documents/Git/M7011E_AJ/build/src/Weather-Module/index.js:32:9
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
```

the provided url path when put in the browser causes no issus, Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Hi, you should fix your url from `http:api...` to `http://api...` (consider using https). I think because of that axios is interpreting your url as relative and is trying to find it locally where it doesn't exist

Comment: My god, i missed that completely Thank you !